# Do I have to break up my Block RAMs to get full device utilization?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, ram, ise

I have a Spartan3E 250K FPGA. I have a dual-mismatched-port block RAM implemented. According to my calculations, making a 8Kbyte RAM should be possible. However, ISE will change my block RAM to a (overmapped) distributed RAM when I try to go over 2Kbytes of RAM. With 2Kbytes though, it says I'm only using 1 of 12 block RAMs

Do I really need to create multiple block RAMs and string them together to get a full 8Kbyte block RAM component?

The code is nearly a straight rip from ISE's template library:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all; 

entity blockram is
  generic (
    --Port A is for general use. Port B is for fetching
    WIDTHA      : integer := 16;
    SIZEA       : integer := 2048;
    ADDRWIDTHA  : integer := 11;
    WIDTHB      : integer := 32;
    SIZEB       : integer := 1024;
    ADDRWIDTHB  : integer := 10
    );

  port(
    Clock   : in  std_logic;
    EnableA    : in  std_logic;
    EnableB    : in  std_logic;
    WriteEnableA    : in  std_logic;
    WriteEnableB    : in  std_logic;
    AddressA  : in  std_logic_vector(ADDRWIDTHA-1 downto 0);
    AddressB  : in  std_logic_vector(ADDRWIDTHB-1 downto 0);
    DataInA    : in  std_logic_vector(WIDTHA-1 downto 0);
    DataInB   : in  std_logic_vector(WIDTHB-1 downto 0);
    DataOutA    : out std_logic_vector(WIDTHA-1 downto 0);
    DataOutB    : out std_logic_vector(WIDTHB-1 downto 0)
  );
end blockram;

architecture Behavioral of blockram is

  function max(L, R: INTEGER) return INTEGER is
  begin
      if L > R then
          return L;
      else
          return R;
      end if;
  end; 

  function min(L, R: INTEGER) return INTEGER is
  begin
      if L < R then
          return L;
      else
          return R;
      end if;
  end; 

  function log2 (val: INTEGER) return natural is
    variable res : natural;
  begin
        for i in 0 to 31 loop
            if (val <= (2**i)) then
                res := i;
                exit;
            end if;
        end loop;
        return res;
  end function log2;

  constant minWIDTH : integer := min(WIDTHA,WIDTHB);
  constant maxWIDTH : integer := max(WIDTHA,WIDTHB);
  constant maxSIZE  : integer := max(SIZEA,SIZEB);
  constant RATIO : integer := maxWIDTH / minWIDTH;

  -- An asymmetric RAM is modelled in a similar way as a symmetric RAM, with an
  -- array of array object. Its aspect ratio corresponds to the port with the
  -- lower data width (larger depth)
  type ramType is array (0 to maxSIZE-1) of std_logic_vector(minWIDTH-1 downto 0);

  -- You need to declare <ram> as a shared variable when :
  --   - the RAM has two write ports,
  --   - the RAM has only one write port whose data width is maxWIDTH
  -- In all other cases, <ram> can be a signal.
  --shared variable ram : ramType := (others => (others => '0'));
  signal ram: ramType;

  signal readA : std_logic_vector(WIDTHA-1 downto 0):= (others => '0');
  signal readB : std_logic_vector(WIDTHB-1 downto 0):= (others => '0');
  signal regA  : std_logic_vector(WIDTHA-1 downto 0):= (others => '0');
  signal regB  : std_logic_vector(WIDTHB-1 downto 0):= (others => '0');




begin

  process (Clock)
  begin
    if rising_edge(Clock) then
      if EnableA = '1' then
        readA <= ram(conv_integer(AddressA));
        if WriteEnableA = '1' then
          ram(conv_integer(AddressA)) <= DataInA;
        end if;
      end if;
      regA <= readA;
    end if;
  end process;

  process (Clock)
  begin
    if rising_edge(Clock) then
      if EnableB = '1' then        
        for i in 0 to RATIO-1 loop
                  -- The read statement below is placed before the write statement on purpose
                  -- to ensure read-first synchronization through the variable mechanism
          readB((i+1)*minWIDTH-1 downto i*minWIDTH)
                <= ram(conv_integer(AddressB & conv_std_logic_vector(i,log2(RATIO))));

        end loop;
      end if;
      regB <= readB;
    end if;
  end process;

  DataOutA <= regA;
  DataOutB <= regB;

end behavioral;
```

Comment: Do you have your dual-port RAM isolated to its own module, and could you share that module with us? There may be some detail about your definition that's preventing ISE from using the blockram at the larger sizes.

Comment: @DaveTweed I added the code. It's nearly a straight rip from ISE's code template for asymmetric dual port RAM

Answer (score 1):

Inferring dual-port with different data widths is a bit of a pain - I gave up (using the template code was a non-starter as it had clearly never been tested with generics other than the defaults)

Hold your nose and use Coregen :(

Comment: I'll just break it up instead(ie, use multiple blockram components). I strongly prefer simulation with ghdl. Also, I noticed that without using the hidden `use-new-parser` option, XST won't synthesize a block RAM ever for me on a Spartan 3E

Comment: Does GHDL not work with  Xilinx's libraries?

Comment: Xilinx libraries can be used in ghdl.